# Can anyone suggest a method to detect the eyelids?

Tags: matlab

I have tried manual detection using LS polynomial fitting [here](http://www.boinkrobotics.com/math/files/Eyelid%20LS%20Poly%20Fit.pdf). But that cannot be used in my project as mine has to be a fully automated system.

Comment: It would be better to move this question to [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why can't you put the logic, that you used to do it manually, in a computer for automation? Furthermore, I think that as-is your question is not yet a programming question. First think in some detail of what you want to do, then try it, and if you get stuck somewhere in the programming ask the question here.

Comment: I would look up concepts such as edge detection, contrast adjustment, conversion between colormaps and formats (B&W, grayscale...)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Scale-Invariant Feature Transform, or SIFT.  [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0wqePj4Mx0) explains it well.  You "train" a detector with one or more images of eyelids, and the detector locates similar regions in the input images.  It's the de facto general purpose feature detector - although more specialized tools like face detectors are faster.

The "Scale-Invariant" part means that it can detect the same object at different sizes and rotations.